# I got a System error in C# post

Tags: c#, post, uwp

It is my first time to ask a question in here (I'm from Asia).

> Platform：UWP 17632
>
> IDE : Visual Studio 2017

Based on the reqiurement of the project， I need to post some information to a website.

I refer the answer about [How to make HTTP POST web request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request/4015346#4015346) Method A.

[image]

Here is my code：

```
public async void PostDataAsync(string pTemperture, string pHumidity, string pFireStatus, string pLightStatus, string pBodyStatus)
   {
       var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
           {
               {"count", "1" },
               {"temperture_0", pTemperture },
               {"Humidity_0", pHumidity },
               {"FireStatus_0", pFireStatus },
               {"LightStatus_0" ,pLightStatus},
               {"BodyDetect_0", pBodyStatus }
           };
       var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
       try
       {
           var response = await client.PostAsync("http://115.159.36.210/api/onehome/upload", content);//Here throw an exception
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response);
           var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(responseString);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.HelpLink);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
           throw;
       }            
   }
```

And then it throws an exception

```
“An error occurred while sending the request.”
```

in

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://115.159.36.210/api/onehome/upload", content);
```

I want to know why and gain the solution which can solve it.
I will be grateful if you can help me.

Comment: Have a look at the inner exception

Comment: Look at this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235131/universal-windows-project-httpclient-exception

Comment: @Kaushik Srinath Thank you!!! I never consider this problem.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommend that use `HttpClient` and the rest of the [`Windows.Web.Http`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http) namespace API to send and receive information using the HTTP 2.0 and HTTP 1.1 protocols within UWP.

For your requirement, you could make a method to package http POST method like the follow

```
public async void SendPostMethod(string url, Dictionary<string, string> param, Action<string> response)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();
    Uri requestUri = new Uri(url);

    var content = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(param);
    try
    {
        httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, content);

        response(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
 this.SendPostMethod("http://115.159.36.210/api/onehome/upload",Param, (res) =>
{

    var response = res;

});
```

And there are official [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HttpClient) and [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient) that you could refer.

Comment: Thank you！I will try it.

Comment: what  exception throw ?

Comment: When I execute the code `httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, content);`, it throw an exception:  A connection with the server could not be established. And the res is :  {"status":-1,"msg":"Error! Invalid Request."}

Comment: Will it be a problem with the webpage?

Comment: Yep,  you could check the http state code, if the code is 200 that means your request successful.

Comment: Do you miss some token or specified Id parameter ?

Comment: emmmmm， the author of this web didn't finish it.So,,,,,,,it is not the code's fault.

Comment: Yep, I get the same json in my side. in general, you need add some authentication in your request header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174301/discussion-between-lifuguan-and-nico-zhu-msft).

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of the server.

The reality is I have not finish the code of the server.

Thus , `{"status":-1,"msg":"Error! Invalid Request."}` is the default result .....